# In Microsoft Windows, Can I administrate the Java Runtime Setting by script?

Tags: java, administrator

Refer to the screenshot, my Windows is Traditional Chinese so I translate to English for you.
In my office, I like to administrate all my users java runtime parameters, can I do it? by group policy? by some login script(bat/vbs/powershell...etc)?
[image: Java setting in Control Panel]

Answer (score 2):

We successfully used the `SETX` command (Set Environment Variable).  Then told it what environment variable to configure `_java_options` and the value to go in there `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Here's our one line batch file

```
setx _java_options -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Good luck!